# MSDeploy - can publish via VS but not msdeploy - 401

Tags: msdeploy

I am trying to recreate the VS publish in MSDeploy so that it can be used cleanly on the build server.

With VS on our local dev machines the publish wizard will work.  If I take that url, use the same username and password I get a 401 from the command line:

[image]

I am tried using the username and machinename\username both ways gave the 401.

The command line, I admit, is slightly different.  It is trying to push some local files out to the server rather than VS building the website and pushing those files out.  The test files are the packaged files in the same format VS does it, but I cant see how this would be anything to do with it.  Unless VS is directly talking to it via IIS sites (on destination machine) and that the destination machines msdeploy is only allowing that type of publish.  But this is a wild guess and don't know how to test / debug that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add authType=Basic to the computername=X,authType=Basic,username=y section